# Trouble with updating IDs and jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make some kind of form, but I'm stuck moving to 3rd step.

My next button does have an incrementing ID like that:

```
$('#to-q-2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("id", "to-q-3");
})
```

So the id is updated. 
But when I click again:

```
$('#to-q-3').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stop');
});
```

nothing happens. I guess jQuery did not update the DOM, but I have no idea how to do it. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the click event to the `document` so that it can look for new elements that were not present at the initial binding of `click` event, this way you can add click events to dynamically added elements. You can do this using:

`$(document).on('click', '#to-q-3', function() {...})`

See working example below:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#to-q-2', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("id", "to-q-3");
});

$(document).on('click', '#to-q-3', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("stop");
});
```

```css
#to-q-2 {
  color: red;
}

#to-q-3 {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to-q-2">Click this div</div>
```